How to run syn-workspace-info in Databricks UCX Migration
I'm trying to work through the Databricks Unity Catalog migration using the UCX tool and am getting this weird error when trying to sync the workspace info. When I run databricks labs ucx sync-workspace-info I get the following error:

I can't find anything online about this error. My account is an Account Administrator, my profiles in the .databrickscfg are configured and authenticated. Any help is appreciated.

You have to auth in account-level in order to run databricks labs ucx sync-workspace-info
Auth can be done by:
databricks auth login --host <account-console-url> --account-id <account-id>

where <account-console-url> is your Databricks account url (not a workspace url). For example, mine is https://accounts.gcp.databricks.com. Also, your <account-id> can be found here
To verify your authentication, simply run:
databricks account groups list

The command line above should give you the proper output.
For more details:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/authentication.html#oauth-user-to-machine-u2m-authentication

Thank you for your comment, although this didn't solve the problem. When I run the first command I am directed to a webpage that says "Authenticated" and get the following result in my terminal:
Profile ACCOUNT was successfully saved
When I run the second command however I get:
Error: invalid Databricks Account configuration
I'm not sure if there is a difference between accounts and profiles but when I run the databricks auth profiles command, I see my account profile on the list with the host value set to my account url and it is listed as valid.
